# Mobile connect templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Which mobile connect template should I use if I am wanting to send outbound message responses depending on a word they text. For example, if they reply YES I want a certain message whereas if they reply NO I need a separate message. Should I just make yes and no different keywords?

Comment: Take a look at the Text Response Message: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_text_response.htm&type=5